# SpringROO+GWT customization

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I want to build a GWT application that doesn't use a database. I thought to use Spring ROO to get the initial configurations for it. A Spring ROO+GWT generated app has:

- RequestFactory based client-server communication
- MVP pattern applied
- Activities, places, browser history management
- [1] UIBinder-based UIs that use *.ui.xml files for UI definitions
- [4] a lot of generated activities in /client/managed/activity
- [5] a lot of generated UIs in /client/managed/ui - all of them use UIBinder
- Spring integration
- [2] Spring MVC integration
- [3] Hibernate(or other JPA implementation) integration

I don't want [1], [2], [3] features from it.

### Questions

1. About [1], I intend to have my own UIs that don't necessarily use UIBinder. How do I do that?
2. What if I want a different logic/layout for the app? Is it safe to remove [4] and [5] and then generate my own MVP components? How do I do that - I don't necessarily care to keep Spring ROO support in the app, I just want to change the scaffold app and build something totally different. I saw that when I add a field in the domain bean, it automatically generate UIs, and [4],[5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the selling points for Roo is that you can [easily remove it](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html) from your project.  Nothing in the Roo-generated code presupposes that you will continue to use Roo indefinitely. The GWT Expenses sample app actually started off as a Roo-generated app, but has become a manually-maintained codebase.

To your first point, UiBinder doesn't do anything that you can't write by hand.  All of the declarative XML code that you would write just gets turned into straight procedural code by the UiBinder Generator.  To remove a UiBinder-based UI, just delete the `.ui.xml` file and the custom `UiBinder` sub-interface.

Comment: Why did GWT Expenses become a ROO-less app? Where can I find the source code for that app? I intend to have a service-only app with POJOs created in these services and returned to client, thus I need RequestFactory with ServiceLocators found only in GWT 2.1.1. Is there any way to keep ROO in these scenarios? Thanks

Comment: About UIBinder, you're right - it is the same as hand written thing, I didn't have enough infos at that point about it.

Comment: The expenses sample app is in GWT's SVN repository [browse](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fexpenses).  The Expenses app was written fairly early on in the GWT+Roo integration process and was also used to drive GWT 2.1.1 feature and widget development.  You could use Roo to only manage your server domain code and roll your GWT app by hand without using the GWT+Roo integration, since it sounds like you'd prefer to build you app in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the expenses app - I'm thinking to use it as a base structure(scaffold) for my project and remove unnecessary parts from it(specific to expenses). I can't really use Roo on server either(I think) because I'm not using an EntityManager(persistence) - I'll have services that return POJOs. Can Roo still help me in this scenario or the only way is to remove it from server-side too?